# Does Android suspend USB devices?

Tags: android, usb, suspend

I'm designing a USB device meant to be connected to an off-the-shelf Android phone. The device is meant to be connected for a long time (hours) and should therefore draw as little power as possible. During this time it monitors a sensor input and, under certain conditions, sends a signal to the host.

In the USB specification there's the notion of "suspend" and "remote wake-up". This is normally used by USB keyboards and mice to wake-up a PC when in sleep mode, and draw less than 1mA before a button is pressed.

I could verify this behavior with a USB mode. On a normally running PC the mouse draws 10 to 30mA, when in sleep mode it goes down to 0.5mA.

I looked for such feature in Android phones, but I couldn't find anything. If I plug a mouse to the USB port of a Samsung Galaxy A12 its consumption always remains at around 10mA, no matter if the screen is off or if the phone is in doze mode. I find this rather surprising, considering how important is for a mobile device to save as much energy as possible.

So I wonder if this feature is actually present in any known Android OS or device, i.e. if a non-rooted Android device can suspend USB devices connected to its host port. Maybe there's some setting that can be enabled?

Comment: Possibly related: https://source.android.com/compatibility/12/android-12-cdd#772_usb_host_mode

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang. It seems that Android 12 devices should allow disabling USB signaling, but by googling those specific words it seems the purpose is to allow company-owned devices to stop people plugging USB devices doing anything other than charging ([link](https://www.sammyfans.com/2021/10/09/android-12-lets-it-admins-disable-usb-data-signaling/)).

Comment: May also be related to supporting legacy Android Open Accessory API: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/custom#connecting-over-usb and https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Alas I didn't. We explored other ideas specifically because we couldn't find any official documentation, and the real-world test went against our expectations.